# Eclipse hangs at "Launching <project name>"

Tags: android, eclipse

Operating System：win7/ubuntu
SDK tools version: 23.0.2
Eclipse version: juno download from google
ADT plug-in version: latest at this time
Platform targeted by my project: 4.4

The problem is :
Eclipse is locked up.

The bottom right "Launching   " progress indicator is alive, going back and forth.

Click anywhere in the Eclipse window (menus, project hierarchy, code windows) has no effect.

I left it untouched for more than an hour, no change and reinstall eclipse does not work;

Each time I encounter the problem,I always restart the eclipse,it works,but i do not want to have  trouble dong this .( project-->clean has no effect.)
In addition,I found this problem ofen appears when I debug my application.

Thanks:-)